# Getting Error when login laravel Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation Users

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Please Help.

I'm Getting Error when login and sometimes the page expired.

How to solved this?

[image]

Comment: What did you exactly do and what did you expect and what did you get? Explain by codes please.

Comment: Have you run the required migrations and in the correct sequence? Also, please can you add any relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Run migrations `php artisan migrate` and check your csrf token for your login form. If you have not added csrf token add it inside your form `<form>@csrf ....</form>`